# Is it possible to display the value of an environment variable in a Tyk Dashboard template file?

Tags: go-templates, tyk

I'm trying to reference an environment variable in Tyk Dashboard.

I set up a `docker-compose.yaml` file containing environment variables:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  tyk-portal:
    image: tykio/portal:v1.3.0
    command: --bootstrap
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    environment:
      - ...
      - MY_VAR=someValue123
```

When I run `docker-compose up`, I can navigate to the Tyk dashboard on `localhost:3001`.

Inside Tyks `top_nav.tmp` template file I'm now trying to display the value of my environment variable `MY_VAR`.
I want use something like this:

```
<p>
{{ .Env.MY_VAR }}
</p>
```

However, nothing is displayed. I cannot find a concrete example in the [docs](https://tyk.io/docs/tyk-dashboard/configuration/) and I'm starting to wonder if referencing an environment variable inside a Tyk template file is at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tyk [bundles](https://tyk.io/docs/transform-traffic/request-body/#go-template-functions) the [Sprig Library (v3)](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/os.html) which has the `env` function. Use it like this:

```
<p>
{{ env "MY_VAR" }}
</p>
```